# Operator as parameter to IF returns SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python

This is a simple calculator, but for some reason, it returns a syntax error in the "if":

```
a = int(input("First number: "))
b = int(input("Second number: "))
operator = input("Type operation '+', '-','*' ou '/' ")

if operator == "+":
    print("The sum is "(a+b)
elif operator == "-":
        print("The subtraction is "(a-b))
elif operator == "*":
    print("A product is "(a*b))
elif operator == "/":
    print("O quotient "(a/b))
```

Comment: print("The sum is "(a+b))

Comment: You are missing a bracket after the `print` in the first `if`.

Comment: Your first print needs an extra ')'

Comment: You need a comma between separate items in your `print` calls.

Answer (score 0):

You have indeed some sintax errors, your function should look like this:

```py
    a = int(input("First number: "))
    b = int(input("Second number: "))
    operator = input("Type operation '+', '-','*' ou '/' ")

    if operator == "+":
        print("The sum is %s"%(a+b))
    elif operator == "-":
        print("The subtraction is %s"%(a-b))
    elif operator == "*":
        print("A product is %s"%(a*b))
    elif operator == "/":
        print("O quotient %s"%(a/b))
    else:
       print("something here")
```

Also as suggested by @khelwood:

```py
    a = int(input("First number: "))
    b = int(input("Second number: "))
    operator = input("Type operation '+', '-','*' ou '/' ")

    if operator == "+":
        print("The sum is ",(a+b))
    elif operator == "-":
        print("The subtraction is ",(a-b))
    elif operator == "*":
        print("A product is ",(a*b))
    elif operator == "/":
        print("O quotient ",(a/b))
    else:
       print("something here")
```

Also in Python3, we have a new way to format string that you could use:

```py
    a = int(input("First number: "))
    b = int(input("Second number: "))
    operator = input("Type operation '+', '-','*' ou '/' ")

    if operator == "+":
        print(f"The sum is {a+b}")
    elif operator == "-":
        print(f"The subtraction is {a-b}")
    elif operator == "*":
        print(f"A product is {a*b}")
    elif operator == "/":
        print(f"O quotient {a/b}")
    else:
       print("something here")
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Khelwood's was used.